Router redirects immediately
I have a route config:
{
    path: 'dashboard',
    component: UserDashboardPageComponent,
    title: 'Panel',
    children: [
      {
        path: 'summary',
        component: DashboardSummaryComponent,
        title: 'Podsumowanie',
      },
      {
        path: 'official-exams',
        component: OfficialMaturaExamsComponent,
        title: 'Arkusze maturalne',
      },
      {
        path: 'mock-exams',
        component: MockMaturaExamsComponent,
        title: 'Próbne matury',
      },
      {
        path: 'exams-exercises',
        component: MaturaExamsExcercisesComponent,
        title: 'Zadania maturalne',
      }...

and then i have a page with router outlet:
<section class="flex h-[100vh]">
  <app-dashboard-navigation class="min-w-[20rem]"></app-dashboard-navigation>
  <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</section>

to navigate i have a card:
<div
  class="flex gap-5 justify-left items-center text-center pl-5 group hover:cursor-pointer m-3 backdrop-blur-md"
  [routerLink]="route"
>
  <ng-icon
    class="text-3xl group-hover:text-cyan-600 transition-all duration-300"
    [name]="icon"
  ></ng-icon>
  <p
    class="text-xl font-bold group-hover:text-cyan-600 transition-all duration-300"
  >
    {{ title }}
  </p>
</div>

and then:
@for(opt of menu; track opt){
    <app-dashboard-nav-card
      [icon]="opt.icon"
      [title]="opt.title"
      [route]="opt.route"
    ></app-dashboard-nav-card>
    }

from the list of items:
  menu: any[] = [
    {
      icon: 'tablerAtom',
      title: 'Arkusze maturalne',
      route: 'official-exams',
    },
    {
      icon: 'tablerPaperclip',
      title: 'Arkusze próbne',
      route: 'mock-exams',
    },
    {
      icon: 'tablerNotebook',
      title: 'Zadania maturalne',
      route: 'exams-exercises',
    },
  ];

The problem is that when i enter the official-exams (dashboard/official-exams) through the navbar, i get immediately redirected to the  'dashboard' and i have to use browser built in go back to access the resource. I can manually enter the url and it works fine, but when i try to enter any component that should be inside router-outlet i get immediately redirected to dashboard.
I get no error the url is bad, and after all i can go back to right url. The urls are good, but i get redirected all the time.
Why? How to fix it?

there is some code that redirects you, try commenting out all navigate calls and checking if that is the problem

Do you have redirect somewhere in your route config? Pay particular attention to { path: '', redirectTo: ... }.

Do you have 2 router outlets? One in AppComponent and another one in UserDashboardPageComponent?

Hi, thanks for trying to help. In whole code repo theres no redirect statement, and yes, i do have 2 router outlet.

maybe try with "route: '/official-exams'" or "route: '/dashboard/official-exams'".

Use Absolute Routes in routerLink
Currently, you are using relative routes for navigation (route: 'official-exams'). If your navigation happens outside the dashboard path, it may result in incorrect URL resolution.
To ensure the routes resolves correctly, prepend the full path:
menu = [{ 
  icon: 'tablerAtom',
  title: 'Arkusze maturalne',
  route: '/dashboard/official-exams', // Absolute route
}]

